# bouncycastle jar runtime exception

Tags: java, jar, bouncycastle

I follow this instruction to add bouncycastle (already tried dynamic and static installation): http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation and it works fine in the IDE and Junit Test program.

But when I run the maven packaging jar. It always throw an exception: `NoSuchProviderException in HmacSHA512.getInstance`.

Anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Successfully compiled.

The problem is JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC.

The signature of Bouncy Castle are indispensable when executing fat jar. Therefore, the Bouncy Castle jar should not be packed into your project fat jar file. it should be excluded from your fat jar and copy the bcprov-jdk15on jar to other directory and designate this directory using .

Example: click [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dropwizard-user/Grp5atjNSTU/OwpfeQxuRM8J)